# two different movable images on Jpanel

Tags: java

I'm creating a two player game and I'm having some difficulties with creating two movable player images. should I just make a player one and player two claas or is this amateuristic? here is my current non working code:

```
package game;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Speler {
private Image image;
private int x = 0, y = 0, velX=0, velY = 0;
private int eerste;
public Speler(int welke){

 welke = eerste;
 if( welke < 10){ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\gil\\Pictures\\blauw vierkant.png" );
 image = ii.getImage();
 x = 40;
 y = 160;}

 else{ ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\gil\\Pictures\\paars vierkant.png" );
 image = ii.getImage();
 x = 520;
 y = 10;}
```

}

```
public void move(){
    if (x<0)
    {
        velX = 0;
        x=0;
    }
    if (x>545)
    {
        velX = 0;
        x=545;
    }
    if (y<0)
    {
        velY = 0;
        y=0;
    }
    if (y>323)
    {
        velY = 0;
        y=323;
    }
    x = x + velX;
    y = y + velY;

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int c = e.getKeyCode();
    if (eerste < 10){
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
    {
        velX = -1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_Z)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = -1;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_D)
    {
        velX = 1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if (c == KeyEvent.VK_S)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 1;}
    else{
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            velX = -1;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            velX = 0;
            velY = -1;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            velX = 1;
            velY = 0;
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            velX = 0;
            velY = 1;
        }
    }
    }
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    velX = 0;
    velY = 0;
}
public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}
public void Drawspeler(Graphics g){


            Graphics2D g2d1 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2d1.drawImage(image,x,y,null);

            }

}

 package game;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private Timer tm;
private Speler speler1;
private Speler speler2;
public Board(){

addKeyListener(new Indrukken());
setFocusable(true);
setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
speler1 = new Speler(1);
speler2 = new Speler(50);
tm = new Timer(10, this);
tm.start();
```

}

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    speler1.Drawspeler(g);
    speler2.Drawspeler(g);

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    speler1.move();
    speler2.move();
    repaint();
}  
private class Indrukken extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        speler1.keyPressed(e);
        speler2.keyPressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    speler1.keyReleased(e);
    speler2.keyReleased(e);
    } 
    }
```

}

Comment: See the `KeyboardAnimation` example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a working example with two images.

Comment: But my way won't even paint the two images why is this